# Reading data line by line in node.js (readline) but object always empty when done

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I'm a total noob with Node.js (but I've been a developer for 21 years, fwiw).  I'm attempting to write a small app that will read in a csv file and parse it into an object.  Here's the code:

```
var getFile = (filename) => {

var columns = [],
    x = 0,
    linereader = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('./import/' + filename)
    });

linereader.on('line', function (line) {
    columns[x] = {};
    columns[x].data = line.split("|");
    x++;
}).on('close', () => {
    return columns;
});

};
```

It works fine until time to return the object `columns`, which via the debugger is being created perfectly.  But, once outside of the `linereader` section, it's empty.

I tried adding the `.on("close")` portion a few minutes ago and it made no difference, even if I passed `columns` into it.

Is this thing being asynchronous?  How can I get it to return my object?  Thank you!

Comment: where does the "readline" interface come from? nvm, it's a native module

Comment: Node JS is async out of the box. You shouldn't return anything on the close event as a result. Instead you should do what you want to do with columns in the close event.

.on('close', () => {
    console.log(columns);
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node JS is async this means you must wait until file read operation finished and then use `columns` variable, so you can't return columns right after line execution or even in `.on("close")`, instead pass a `callback` function as argument to your function and run `callback` when `columns` ready

```
var getFile = (filename, callback) => {
    var columns = [],
        x = 0,
        linereader = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream('./import/' + filename)
        });

    linereader.on('line', function (line) {
        columns[x] = {};
        columns[x].data = line.split("|");
        x++;
    }).on('close', () => {
        callback(columns);
    });
};

// usage
getFile("path/to/file", (columns) => {
    console.log(columns.length)
})
```